# Prevent css transition from overlapping on multiple mouseenter

Tags: jquery, css

So, I have this `svg` that triggers an outlining animation on hover. The problem is that if I keep hovering off and on while the animation is not complete yet, it completely breaks the sequence and things start to become messy and out of sync.

I'd like that the once the `svg` is hovered, the animation were executed till the end without any interruption, no matter if it's still hovered or not. And then, only once the whole animation is already finished, it can be triggered again by the user.

I believe there's a simple solution for it, but I'm quite new to jQuery, so I really don't know how to deal with it very well yet.

```js
$(".main-logo").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".draw").bind('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("anim");
    $(".draw").unbind('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration');
  });
});

$(".main-logo").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".draw").addClass("anim");
  console.log(1);
});

$(".main-logo").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".draw2").bind('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("anim");
    $(".draw2").unbind('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration');
  });
});

$(".main-logo").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".draw2").addClass("anim");
  console.log(1);
});

$(".main-logo").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".logo-box").bind('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("anim");
    $(".logo-box").unbind('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration');
  });
});

$(".main-logo").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".logo-box").addClass("anim");
  console.log(1);
});
```

```css
.logo-box {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .45s ease;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 70px;
}

.logo-box.anim {
  transform: scale(1.07) translateY(5px);
  transition: all .15s ease;
}

.draw {
  fill: #000;
}

.draw2 {
  position: relative;
  fill: #fbd100;
}

.draw.anim {
  stroke: #fbd100;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-dasharray: 815;
  stroke-dashoffset: 815;
  animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.draw2.anim {
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: animate2 .5s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.40s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  0% {
    fill: #000
  }
  4% {
    fill: transparent
  }
  60% {
    fill: transparent
  }
  95% {
    stroke-width: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #000;
    stroke-width: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.2)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-box">
  <svg version="1.1" class="main-logo" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="40px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 700 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 650 269;" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect class="draw" width="700" height="800" />
    <g transform="translate(535,146)">
      <rect class="draw2" width="130" height="130"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, you should not just link `jsfiddle` or some other code testing providers. Your question is practically worthless if the provider shuts down his service. Stackoverflow has his own code testing service. Please edit your question according to [this site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). You might also want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: My bad, didn't know I could add the whole snippet. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the mouseleave, just capture animation end and remove the iteration in css.

```js
$(".draw, .draw2").on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
  $(this).addClass("done");
  if (!$(".draw:not(.done), .draw2:not(.done)").length) {
    $(".draw.done, .draw2.done").removeClass("anim").removeClass("done");
  }
});

$(".main-logo").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".draw, .draw2").addClass("anim");
});
```

```css
.logo-box {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .45s ease;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 70px;
}

.logo-box.anim {
  transform: scale(1.07) translateY(5px);
  transition: all .15s ease;
}

.draw {
  fill: #000;
}

.draw2 {
  position: relative;
  fill: #fbd100;
}

.draw.anim {
  stroke: #fbd100;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-dasharray: 815;
  stroke-dashoffset: 815;
  animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.draw2.anim {
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: animate2 .5s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.40s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  0% {
    fill: #000
  }
  4% {
    fill: transparent
  }
  60% {
    fill: transparent
  }
  95% {
    stroke-width: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #000;
    stroke-width: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.2)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-box">
  <svg version="1.1" class="main-logo" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="40px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 700 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 650 269;" xml:space="preserve">
   <rect class="draw" width="700" height="800" />
     <g transform="translate(535,146)"><rect class="draw2" width="130" height="130"/></g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! This seems to fix the overlapping on sequential hovers, but there's a small detail: .draw2's animation ends a bit after .draw's animation, so if hover the area while .draw has already finished but .draw2 is still running, it triggers .draw and the animation of that element begins while the other one hasn't finished yet.

How could I deal with it and make that all the 3 animations are triggered only after all them are complete?

Comment: Add done class to each element when it has completed then run a check if both have the done class. If they are both done then remove the `.done` and `.anim` class. This will prevent the issue you just described. I have edited my post with corrections.

Comment: You could probably get away with just watching .draw2 instead but watching both like this will ensure that neither is running.